# Html input attributes not working

Tags: html

I have a form which has input type="email" & input type="password" both has the required attribute on submitting the form the email is not validated (it accepts simple text for eg 'abcde') and both the field also accepts null value though required attribute is written

```
 <form> 

    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="role" value="tbl_staff_details" checked />Institute/Branch
      <input type="radio" name="role" value="tbl_student_details" />Student/Parent

   <div id="msg" style="color: red;margin-top: 1%"></div>

</div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback" style="margin-top: 5%">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="mail" required />
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="pwd" required />
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="checkbox icheck">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" id="signin">Sign In</button>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
  </div>
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is? Are you trying to make sure the email field is a valid email? Where's your end form tag? Where's your submit input?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 0):

The checks you describe will happen when the form is submitted.

You don't have a submit button.

Remove `type="button"` (so that the button element uses the default of `type="submit"`).

Answer (score 0):

For the "required" attribute to effect, you must have a button type "submit" and all of them need to be put in the same "form" part, as my quick check, you miss button type "submit" and I also don's see your

Answer (score -1):

Ok, looks like you have quite a few issues here. I'm going to guess on what you're asking, because it's not quite clear, but I do see you have a lot of issues here.

First: If you want to validate an email, you need to actually validate it through code. The browser's not going to magically do this for you. You need to setup these constraints. You can easily do it with the pattern attribute in HTML. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Alternatively, you can validate things with javascript, as well.

Second: You are probably submitting your form through some non-standard way. If you want your "required" attributes to work, then you need to submit the form typically with -

```
<input type="Submit">
```

Answer (score -1):

I just tried simply to run your code

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="mail" required />
```

and it works just fine for me, the email field is required.

This is exempel of code.

```
<form>
  Username: 

  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="mail" required />

  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

You just med to have button with type submit.

Comment: Upvoted because of unjustified downvote with no explanation.